# Add development or debugging tools layer to existing docker containers

Tags: debugging, docker, containers

I have many docker containers and I would like to execute additional development tasks in them ad-hoc (`gcc -O0` and `gdb`).

I could install additional software as `deb` or `rpm` packages (headers, libraries), mount additional volumes (e.g. dotfiles, `vim` plugins), add users or bake new, derivative containers (but this would at least in theory lead to combinatorial explosion of containers I need to track).

What is the recommended and proven method for doing this?